# Docker runs on WIndows and only on one of two Linux systems

Tags: docker

I have a docker image that I have built that runs on my windows laptop as expected.  When I copy and load it on to one of my two Linux systems I get this error when I run docker logs:

> Error: 'docker/semantic_search_django/gunicorn.conf' doesn't exist

When I inspect the running container on Windows I can see that "missing" file!  Furthermore, if I copy and load the same docker image to my second Linux system, it runs as expected.

This issue just happened today.  I've been having success on all 3 systems for the past couple of months until today.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Both Linux systems are running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

I've tried renamed the images, I've stopped and started the docker daemon, I've even restarted both Linux boxes.

Here are the commands I have used:

```
docker pull my.artifactory.com/ciee_ssrdjango

docker-compose up -d
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
     image: m.artifactory.com/ciee_ssrdjango
     env_file:
       - proxy.env
       - django.env
     container_name: ciee_ssrdjango
     volumes:
       - query-results-volume:/code
     expose:
       - "${SSRDJANGO_PORT}"
     extra_hosts:
       dbhost: ${POSTGRES_DOCKER_IP}
     depends_on:
       - db
     networks:
       - ssr_network
networks:
  ssr_network:
    external: true
volumes:
  postgresql-volume:
    external: true
  query-results-volume:
    external: true
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
#prevents being asked to set TZ
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update -y && \
    apt -y upgrade && \
    apt install -y python3-pip && \
    apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libpq-dev python3-dev && \
    apt install -y software-properties-common python3.8

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

ENV TZ=US/Eastern
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt update -y & apt install gcc libxml2-dev libxslt-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib postgresql-plpython-10 --no-install-recommends unixodbc-dev unixodbc libpq-dev -y

RUN mkdir /code # && mkdir /code/ciee
RUN pip install nltk
RUN export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code
RUN useradd -m user && chmod 777 /home/user && mkdir /code/query_results && chmod 777 /code/query_results
USER user
CMD ["gunicorn", "semantic_search_django.wsgi:application", "--config", "docker/semantic_search_django/gunicorn.conf", "--keep-alive", "600"]
```

Here's the thing, I've been using these files and commands successfully for many weeks.

Comment: `When I copy and load it to one of my two Linux systems` <= which commands did you use to do this exactly? Did you go through a registry (push/pull)? Which command do you use to run your container? Are you mounting any volumes? How do you push that "missing" file inside the image (a Dockerfile could help)? ...

Comment: Added details in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can make one assumption. You are mounting query-results-volume into /code directory in container and your conf file is located inside it. The volume persists between containers – that's the nature of the volumes. So, somehow, the file in question (or even the folder) has been removed from the volume on the problem machine and now container can not get it.

Comment: Yes, I considered something like that so I removed the volume on one my of my attempts and re-created it and re tried and same results.  Besides, the conf file is not in the volume.

Comment: Is docker system prune -a the best way to clean up any orphaned docker images including all layers?  I keep wondering if I have a weird caching issue?

Comment: How it can be not in the volume? You workdir is /code co you CMD runs from that folder. And you designate a relative path to conf file, so it is located in /code/docker/semantic_search_django/gunicorn.conf. Then you mount a volume into the /code folder, so all contents of this folder, including gunicorn.conf file gets into the volume. Anyway, you can try to start the service with docker-compose run in interactive mode, cd into folder and see, what happened to the file

Comment: The volume maps to a sub folder of code called query results

Comment: No, it does not.
volumes:
       - query-results-volume:/code
does not map query-results-volume folder into code folder, it mappes query-result-volume folder contents into code folder, overwriting anything, which is in it originally. If query-results-volume is empty, than the code folder contents gets into it, if it is not empty, then the code folder contents in image gets completely replaced by query-results-volume folder contents in container.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are correct.  I'll try changing the mapping to just the sub folder I want persisted.  Thanks.

Comment: However, it doesn't explain the the different results among the 3 servers.

Comment: Once I mapped just the folder I wanted in teh persistent volume - all was well.

Comment: About different results - hard to say, but. as far as I can see, you did not put here your full compose file. So is there, by any chance, the other service, which shares this volume with the "web" service